# Keeping directory search results of ftw function

Tags: c, libc

what I have to do is recursively get ".mp3" archives from a determined pre-specified directory and its subdirectories. I did not have a problem getting the mp3's and printing them on console. I am using the ftw function specified in http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Working-with-Directory-Trees.html#Working-with-Directory-Trees, its call-back function would look like this:

```
/* Call-back of ftw function*/

int filter_mp3s(const char *dir_name, const struct stat *status, int typeflag){

    if (typeflag == FTW_D){

        struct dirent **mp3list;
        int num_archives;
        int counter;

        num_archives = scandir (dir_name, &mp3list, select_mp3_ext, alphasort);

        /* print mp3 names */
        if (num_archives > 0) for (counter = 0; counter <= num_archives - 1; counter++) printf("%s\n", mp3list[counter]->d_name);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I really want to do is put the names of the files into a GTK combo-box widget. Problem is, that function returns an int type and the function is not flexible with its parameters so I could "save" in something the entries. In other words, mp3's are found but I have no idea how I could keep the results in order to load them in the combo-box in other function. I do not want to use global variables...
I'm new into this, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the callback doesn't have a customer argument (usually a void*) which appears to be the case, you will have to put found data into a global variable, which is unfortunate.
If that's a problem (i.e. you are in a multithreaded environment) you will have to implement your own version of recursive directory traversal using opendir interface.  It's not difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much... Well, I did that using scandir but still have the same problem since its prototype is: int scandir (const char *dir, struct dirent ***namelist, int (*selector) (const struct dirent *), int (*cmp) (const void *, const void *))

Comment: It doesn't have a customer argument either... Would you recommend me then simply using a global variable or maybe creating a temporary file? (sorry for double post, accidentally pressed enter key)

Comment: I would just opendir and then readdir calling your function recursively.  Then you pass the list of found files and do your own extension matching, then put the matching file names into that list.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX

Comment: At the end, I found using a global variable convenient. Thank you very much for your help! I solved my problem!

Comment: Keep in mind that global variables are usually not the best way of doing things.  Also if you find an answer helpful you should usually accept it (hit the checkmark next to it), this will make people more likely to answer your subsequent questions.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in here, checked! In this case, it seems to me that using a global variable also allows me to split my program in 2 source files. In one of them I only have GTK code, so I don't have to refer to archives from it, just call functions from the other source...